# Angular tab group with asynchronously loading tab contents. Contents must be another component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I am trying to pass component tag from my ts file but getting it as a string. Please help

chat-list.component.ts

```
export interface ExampleTab {
  label: string;
  content: string;
 }

  asyncTabs: Observable<ExampleTab[]>;

constructor() {
this.asyncTabs = Observable.create((observer: Observer<ExampleTab[]>) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    observer.next([
      {label: 'First', content: '<app-chart-finance></app-chart-finance>'},
      {label: 'Second', content:'<app-chart-finance></app-chart-finance>'},
      {label: 'Third', content: '<app-chart-finance></app-chart-finance>'},
    ]);
  }, 1000);
});
```

chat-list.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(asyncTabs | async) === null">
Loading tabs...
</ng-container>
<mat-tab-group>
 <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of asyncTabs | async">
  <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{tab.label}}</ng-template>
  {{table.content}}
 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I am getting {{table.content}} as a string. But I want to show the dom of the particular component. I declare content as a string. Maybe that is why I am getting it as a string. So what kind of changes I need to make to get my desired output.

Thank you all for your support.

Comment: I am not sure about the way you are doing but I think ofcourse you will get it as string, as angular won't render the template as you are doing instead you should opt for Dynamic Component Loader ref: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader